# Using NPM `redis` package, .exists(...) always returns true. Why?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a little Node.js project with Redis that is in development.  What I am currently seeing is that `client.exists(anything)` returns true, even when that key does not exist in the Redis store.  Here is some code to demonstrate what I am doing.

```
const key = 'k'
const content = 'blah blah'
client.rpush(key, content)
```

I run the above code and I stop.  Now, on the command line, I do the following:

```
> redis-cli
:6379> exists k
true
:6379> exists foo
false
```

Awesome!  As expected.  Now, I run the following code back in Node.js:

```
const key = 'k'
if(client.exists(key)) console.log('should print')
if(client.exists('foo')) console.log('should not print')
```

Unfortunately, the result I'm getting in console output is:

```
should print
should not print
```

Why is Redis in Node.js reporting that something exists when Redis on the CLI reports, as expected, that thing does not exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're using the library wrong, as it's asynchronous.

If you [read the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#usage-example), you'll find that you need to pass in a result callback (or [promisify the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#promises) to use promises instead).

```js
client.exists(key, (err, ok) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(ok);
});
```